# Match the type of a Result<>

Tags: rust, reqwest

Here's an example:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let body = get_pokemon(&args[1]).await;

    // here

    let pokemon = parse_response(body);
}

struct Pokemon {}

async fn get_pokemon(pokemon: &String) -> reqwest::Result<String> {
    let body = reqwest::get(format!("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{}", pokemon))
        .await?
        .text()
        .await?;

    Ok(body)
}

async fn parse_response(response: String) -> Pokemon {}
```

`body` is of type `Result<String, Error>`, is there a way to match what the get_pokemon function returns with the `match` keyword or something similar? i.e. if it returns an error then do this, if a String, do this, etc.

Comment: Yes, using `match` is a pretty common pattern as seen [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/).

Comment: I think that's get_pokemon should be return an Result<reqwest::Result, reqwest::Error>. You can found several example in https://dev.to/pintuch/rust-reqwest-examples-10ff

Answer (score 1):

with Rust it is very common to match for the return type of a function that returns `Result<T,E>` where `T` is any type that is returned on success and `E` is an error type that is returned in case of an error.
What you could do is:

```
match body {
   Ok(pokemon) => {
      parse_response(body);//looking at get_pokemon `pokemon` will be of type String here
   }
   Err(e) => { // 'e' will be your error type
      eprintln!("Error! {:?}", e)
   }
}
```

Your function is returning a `reqwest::Result<String>`. Without having worked with `reqwest` I cannot give advice on handling this specific `Result`. This declaration looks similar to `std::io::Result<T>` which is a shorthand for `std::io::Result<T, std::io::Error>`. That means You should expect your `pokemon` to be of type `String` or some error type.